# Excluding folders in do loop for S3

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

I'm using the following loop:

```
for path in /var/www/*; do
    [ -d "${path}" ] || 
    dirname="$(basename "${path}")"
    /usr/bin/s3cmd sync "/var/www/${dirname}" s3://folder
done
```

How can i for example exclude folders of files named for example cache or node_modules?

Looking forward to hear from u!

Answer (score 0):

Use case statement with the for loop. Try this:

```
 for path in `/bin/ls /var/www` do
        case "$path" in
                cache*)
                        #skip this
                        continue
                        ;;
                *)
                        #process these 
                        dirname="$(basename "${path}")"
                        /usr/bin/s3cmd   sync "/var/www/${dirname}" s3://folder 
                        ;;
        esac 
done
```

Comment: Thanks! And is it just comma seperated if i want more folders?:)

Comment: It's giving a syntax error as well though near case, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is simple, you could try the following:

```
for path in `/bin/ls /var/www | grep -v "cache"` do
  [ -d "${path}" ] || 
  dirname="$(basename "${path}")"
  /usr/bin/s3cmd sync "/var/www/${dirname}" s3://folder
done
```

Alternatively, using positional params, [, and var. substitution you could have

```
./script.sh $1 $2 $3
```

and have it variable, if that is useful towards your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement with the for loop, like this:

```
for path in /var/www/*; do
      name=$(basename "$path")
      case "$name" in
            cache|node_modules)
                    continue
                    ;;
            *)
                    /usr/bin/s3cmd   sync "$path" s3://folder 
                    ;;
       esac 
done
```